When does an inner product on $C(K)$ come from integration?
Let $K$ be a compact Hausdorff space and suppose $\langle \cdot, \cdot \rangle$ is an inner product on $C(K)$ such that $\langle f, g \rangle \ge 0$ whenever $f(t),g(t)\ge 0$ for all $t \in K$. It follows that the inner product is bounded, so it induces a bounded positive map $T \colon C(K \times K) \to \mathbb{R}$ satisfying $T(f \otimes g) = \langle f, g \rangle$ via identifying $C(K \times K)$ with the projective tensor product $C(K)\otimes_\pi C(K)$. By the Riesz representation theorem there is a positive Borel measure $\mu$ on $K\times K$ such that
$$
\langle f, g \rangle = \int_{K\times K}f(x)g(y)\,\mathrm{d}\mu(x,y)
$$
if I'm not mistaken. My question is:

Is $\mu$ concentrated on the diagonal $D := \{(x,x) \colon x \in K\}$, because $\langle \cdot, \cdot \rangle$ is an inner product on $C(K)$?

I would like to add that I'm not an expert in measure theory.

Hint: use partitions of unity associate to an open cover of $K$ made out of small open sets

Sorry, but I don't understand whether this hint is designed to illustrate that the answer to the question is yes, or no. Can you please elaborate some more?

The identification $C(K\times K ) = C(K) \otimes_\pi C(K)$ is not correct i think, it should be $\otimes_\epsilon$ (injective tensor product).
